# How do I take multiple arguments in a closure and print them?

Tags: functional-programming, rust, closures

I have a call to `env::vars_os` and would like to print all of them in a functional manner:

```
env::vars_os()
    .map(|(k, v)| println!("k : {:?}, v : {:?} \n", k, v));
```

This prints nothing, but the article [Destructuring and Pattern Matching](http://pzol.github.io/getting_rusty/posts/20140417_destructuring_in_rust/) indicates this should be possible.

Comment: "warning: unused result which must be used: iterator adaptors are lazy and do nothing unless consumed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for `vars_os()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.vars_os.html), we see that it is an iterator over tuples, which have the syntax `(a, b)`. So, changing your code to

```
env::vars_os()
    .map(|(k, v)| println!("k : {:?}, v : {:?} \n", k, v));
```

should do the trick.

The syntax you are using would destructure into a struct, only you left out the struct's name, which would precede the curly braces.

---

Iterators in Rust are lazily evaluated, which means none of the code in the `map` is executed until the iterator is consumed. You can do this by calling `collect()`. However, the idiomatic way to do it would be to put code that has side-effects (such as printing) in a `for` loop instead of a `map`:

```
for (k, v) in env::vars_os() {
    println!("k : {:?}, v : {:?} \n", k, v);
}
```

Comment: I did discover this by looking at the example the page has, and changed my question accordingly. but doing this does not print anything ?

Comment: I see, thank you. I will mark this answer as correct and change the title to reflect the question more accurately